# Como puedo retornar correctamente un array en php?

Tags: php, array

estuve viendo varias preguntas pero ninguna respuesta de ellas sufragami problema. tengo implementado un sistema de **leveling** en mi web con php, y todo bien hasta que creo la función para obtener los datos del nivel en base a la experiencia obtenida.

```
//* Función para obtener el Nivel
    public function setLvl($exp ,$lvl){
        $minExp = $this->getExpRank($lvl-1);
        $maxExp = $this->getExpRank($lvl);
        if ($exp >= $minExp && $exp <= $maxExp || $exp == 0) {
            $porcent = (($exp - $minExp)*100) / ($maxExp - $minExp);
            $data = [$maxExp,$exp,$porcent];
            return $data;
        }else{
            $lvl++;
            $this->setLvl($exp,$lvl);
        }
    }
```

Le paso por parámetros la experiencia que posee y el nivel primario que es 1 (esto último es por estilo propio). Lo que pasa es q me retorna un array vacío mientras que el resto de funciones que tengo implementadas si funcionan correctamente, sin embargo al poner `echo (array)[(indice)]` o `var_dump(array)` si me lo muestra en mi sitio al usar `$user->getLvl();` directamente o `echo $user->getLvl();` ($user es debido a que lo estoy llamando la funcion desde una clase).

Resumiendo, mi problema es que (a mi entender) al php no de interesa devolverme el array con `return` :(

Con `return`...[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me sale nada (utilizando `echo`, que al menos debería decirme que no puedo mostrar un `array` como `string`)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando hago un `var_dump` me dice que es nulo el `return`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con `echo` me sale correcto, pero no es lo que necesito
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco cualquier ayuda de antemano y espero haberme dado a entender.

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Qué es lo que funciona  (muestra algo) y qué es lo que no fuciona (no muestra nada)? ¿Por qué haces una llamada que sería recursiva en el `else`?

Comment: @A.Cedano esa llamada es porque si la experiencia no entra entre las condiciones del if, aumenta el nivel y vuelve a comprobar hasta que se cumplen los parametro del if y es q llena y devuelve el array con los valores necesarios. Y no pongo mas porque el código está bastante enrredado como para ponerlo.

Comment: Depura las variables que están en juego, por ejemplo: `var_dump($data);` ¿qué muestra? Depura también: `var_dump($porcent);` y además: `var_dump($maxExp);`  y `var_dump($minExp);`   y `var_dump($exp);`  y `var_dump($lvl);`  y `var_dump` de todo lo que esté interviniendo en ese código, sin duda verás dónde está el problema.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya lo solucioné, me estaba entrando en el else y por eso no me devolvia nada. la condición de que si es ==0 estaba mal escrita. Al poner >= 0 se solucionó. Perdona el tiempo perdido es que estaba estresado y no hallaba el problema. Gracias por los comentarios. Sl2.